# Canvas not drawing in JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I get this error: "cannot read property 'getContext' of null"
I looked up others with this issue, all of them had their JS running before their HTML div was created, but that is not the case for me.
I have linked a JSFiddle with my code, but it doesn't work well because I have fixed elements.
Someone please help, I have no idea what is going on.
JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/alec935/Ln7yghbx/1/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
    <title>Snake</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="snake.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="game">
    <div id="play">
    <canvas id="playBoard"></canvas>
    <script src="snake.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div id="credits"><h1><i>Snake Game</i>, designed by Alec xxxxx</h1></div>
    <div id="info"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes pulsate {
  0% {color:white}
  50% {color:black;}
  100% {color:white}
}

body {
    background-image:url(images/snaxe.jpg);
    background: fill;
}

#game{
    width:1450px;
    height:800px;
    background-color:black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
}

#credits {
    color: white;
    font-size: 19px;
    text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px -1px 4px, rgb(255, 255, 0) 0px -2px 10px, rgb(255, 128, 0) 0px -10px 20px, rgb(255, 0, 0) 0px -18px 40px;
    animation: pulsate 4s infinite;
}

#play{
    width:720px;
    height:720px;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:1;
}

#playBoard {
    width:720px;
    height:720px;
    z-index:0;
}

#info{
    position:fixed;
    top:8px;
    right:115px;
    width:730px;
    height:800px;
    background-color:white;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
var snakeX, snakeY;
var fruitX, fruitY;
var gameOver = true;
var direction = 0; //0 = null, 1 = left, 2 = right, 3 = up, 4 = down

function Draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("playBoard");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //Snake
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth="5";
    ctx.strokeStyle="green";
    ctx.fillRect(385,385,50,50);

}


function Setup() {
    gameOver = false;
    Draw();
}

window.onload = Setup;
});
```

Edit: I had a typo in my canvas element. This has since been fixed. The problem still persists, however.

Comment: sorry about that. Im not using jQuery for any functions in this program yet, though

Comment: No need to be sorry, just fix that error and any others that pop up in the developer console. Press F12 and look at the console tab.

Comment: I have no idea how to properly include jQuery in jsfiddle. It isn't a problem in my browser, the console only shows the error I outlined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your HTML. Your id is misplaced.

```
<canvas>id="playBoard"</canvas>
```

should be

```
<canvas id="playBoard"></canvas>
```

Comment: you're right, but it still doesn't work even when I fixed this

Comment: `window.onload = Setup();` should be `window.onload = Setup`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on the canvas element. Change this:

```
<canvas>id="playBoard"</canvas>
```

to this:

```
<canvas id="playBoard"></canvas>
```

In other words, put the id on the element itself

Comment: I fixed this but the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to select the element with the id playBoard, but you haven't assigned it to your canvas, probably just a typo.

`<canvas>id="playBoard"</canvas>` should be `<canvas id="playBoard"></canvas>`

Comment: I fixed this but the problem still persists